# HOW TO PROVIDE DataSource To UiComponent <DynamicRows>

Tags: uicomponent, magento-2.1.4, data-provider, dynamic-rows

I've Created A **UIcomponent** form Having  As Below.

```
<dynamicRows name="docrows">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">dynamicRows</item>
                    <item name="addButtonLabel" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New</item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="admin__field-wide" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <container name="record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="positionProvider" xsi:type="string">attachment_options.position</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="path">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                            <!--<item name="source" xsi:type="string">path</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">path</item>-->
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Document</item>
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Themecafe_ProductAttachment/file-preview</item>
                            <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">option.order</item>
                            <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                            <!--<item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>-->
                            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="attachment/index/upload/field/path"/>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <field name="doc_title">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Document Title</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">doc_title</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                            <!--<item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">txt_</item>-->
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                            <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enter Document Title</item>
                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <actionDelete>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </actionDelete>                    
            </container>
        </dynamicRows>
```

Record Inserted Properly Into Database Tables.

Now When I Edit The Record I want That Amount of **DynamicRows** Belongs To Record...

i've tried DataProvider But It Just Not Working.
Is that Any Way That i Can Provide DataSource To `<DynamicRows>` UiComponent Element????